# Sending jwt authentication token from web browser

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I'm building a Java Spring application and I'm implementing the security part. Simple username + password authentication with jwt filter and tokens.

The security part was tested and working well in Postman (both registration and authentication) since Postman provides the `Authorization` tab  in the GUI,  I could pass there the jwt token easily before sending the POST request for the `/login` action.

On the other hand, I observed, when I do the exact same process in the browser, the `authHeader` parameter in the `doFIlterInterval` method was always null, but when I used Postman, I received  the correct authentication token in the `authRequest`.

This is just a clue what I found, the browser might not cause the problem, but this is my best guess right now.

Since, I'm new in web development I didn't figure out when the user send the POST request after login, how can I send the specific jwt token  to the jwt filter by an authentication header (I'm thinking about something similar as I did in Postman). Maybe my approach is completetely wrong, so I'm a little bit lost here.

Thank you.

P.S: Here are a couple of code which might be useful:

`LoginController`'s POST method

```
@PostMapping
    public String login(AuthenticationRequest request, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try{
            authService.authenticate(request);
            return "redirect:/dashboard";
        }catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            model.addAttribute("error", true);
            return "login";
        }
    }
```

The `login.html` template which getting invoked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<div th:if="${error}">
    <p style="color: red;">Incorrect username or password.</p>
</div>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/login}">
    <label for="username">username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required><br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="loginButton">
    <a href="/register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `authenticate` method in the AuthenticationService:

```
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        System.out.println("I'm at authentication");

        var authenticationRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
        authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequest);

        var user = userRepository.findByUsername(request.getUsername()).orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        var refreshToken = jwtService.generateRefreshToken(user);

        revokeAllUserTokens(user);
        saveUserToken(user, jwtToken);

        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .accessToken(jwtToken)
                .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                .build();
    }
```

The `AuthenticationResponse` class contains only the access and refresh tokens

The 'JwtAuthenticationFilter`-s method:

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("I'm in doFilter ");
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        final String jwtToken;
        final String userName;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
                filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }

        jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        userName = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);
        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            System.out.println("Jwt filter username: " + userName);
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwtToken).map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked()).orElse(false);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails) && isTokenValid){
                System.out.println("Jwt filter --> setting contextHolder");
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
```

And last, but not least the `security config`:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/dashboard").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/account").authenticated()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));
        return http.build();
    }
```